# Как лучше организовать обмен данными между приложениями

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sharing

В приложении "А" постаянно появляются новые данные, и это приложение должно передать эти новые данные Приложению "Б"(или уведомить о том что есть новые данные и приложение Б должно как то их быстро получить )

Данные очень быстро меняются(полсекунды, секунды). 
Передача данных тоже должно происходить быстро(между приложениямм).

Идея была такая что нужно данные отправлять broadcast сообщениями.

- Какие можете предложить методы?(более подходящии и унифицированнее).
- Чем плох подход с broadcast?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону ContentProvider и Loaders

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, есть [офф документация](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/) на этот счёт.

Если вам нужно передать данные **конкретному приложению**, то можно через `Intent`:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Хотя, наверно, лучше шарить через [Поставщики контента](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers).